# Why am I getting a 403 for a POST?

Tags: node.js, http, express, post, cheerio

I am using cheerios to scrape for a `_csrf` and express to make a post request:

```
request('http://scdownloader.net/', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);    
    var form = $("#mainForm");

    var _csrf;
    
    // Scrape for _csrf
    for (var i = 0; i < form[0].children.length; i++) {
        var a = form[0].children[i].attribs
        if (a != null) {
            a = a.class
            if (a != null && a === "large-5 columns btn-wrapper") {                
                a = form[0].children[i].children;
                for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    var b = a[i].attribs;
                    if (b != null) {
                        if (b.name != null && b.name === '_csrf') {
                            _csrf = b.value;
                            console.log(_csrf);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }        


    if (_csrf == null) {
        // Callback with error
    }

    var title = "/newpartyarmy/tell-me-the-truth";
    var url = "https://soundcloud.com" + title;

    var form = {
        _csrf: _csrf,
        url : url
    }

    request.post({url:'http://scdownloader.net/download', form: form}, function(err, httpResponse, body){ 
        if (!err && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
            console.log(httpResponse);
        }
        console.log(httpResponse.statusCode);
        console.log(httpResponse.statusMessage);        
     })
  }
});
```

This returns a `403` status code. However, when I go to `scdownload.net` to get the `_csrf` myself and use http://http-post.com/ to POST it, it works. It doesn't work, however, with my scraped version.

Example scraped version: `Ii055I/uIr/44xbG3cB/1581eCjKEY/A9yR6XY88JGg=`
Example manually scraped version: `m2RRexmzE3La1pD168ONDlz0giZlBdoxlUeyaJpBIeE=`

[image: manually scraping]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the site requires the use of cookies. use `jar: true` on request.

Example:
`var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})`

Comment: I added `var request = request.defaults({jar: true})` before the code in my post and I still get a `403` code.